# Cant get the query for AzureDiagnostics to work

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I cant get this query to work. I got this query from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-setup-alerts-virtual-network-gateway-log

But I cant get thru RemoteIP_S. What am I doing wrong?

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where Category == "TunnelDiagnosticLog"
| where _ResourceId == tolower("<RESOURCEID OF GATEWAY>")
| where TimeGenerated > ago(5m) 
| where remoteIP_s == "<REMOTE IP OF TUNNEL>"
| where status_s == "Disconnected"
| project TimeGenerated, OperationName, instance_s, Resource, ResourceGroup, _ResourceId 
| sort by TimeGenerated asc
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the logs would take few hours to get populated in Log Analytic work space, until that the query will fail as elements "remoteIP_s" will not exist to query.

You can wait for some hours, then check if it can work.

There are some issues for tracking this issue, see [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34912) and [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/35381).

Comment: Thank you. I am using Policy Based and this query is not supported. 
Is there any chance there is an other solution? To get an alert if the tunnel is disconnected?

Comment: @RobinJohansson, I didn't know how to do it with Policy Based. But just feel free to comment on the github issues in my post, they maybe provide you some ideas.

Comment: @RobinJohansson, for this specific issue of Policy Based, you can comment on the github issue. And if my post is helpful, could you please help mark it as answer? Thanks.